# How to get data from json column in mssql

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I'm struggling to write a query that gets value from json column with some specific conditions. I have a table named Table1 with a column of type nvarchar(max) named Data that contains some json values. The json itself looks like this:

```
{
"Addresses": [
    {
        "ApartmentNumber": "1",
        "City": "Rome",
        "CountryCode": "IT",
        "HouseNumber": "2",
        "Post": "Rome",
        "PostalCode": "11-111",
        "Region": "Rome",
        "Street": "Italian",
        "StreetPrefix": "St.",
        "TypeCode": "PERMANENT"
    },
    {
        "ApartmentNumber": "11",
        "City": "Madrid",
        "CountryCode": "ES",
        "HouseNumber": "22",
        "Post": "Madrid",
        "PostalCode": "11-111",
        "Region": "Madrid",
        "Street": "Spanish",
        "StreetPrefix": "St.",
        "TypeCode": "CORRESPONDENCE"
    }
],
"Contacts": [
    {
        "TypeCode": "EMAIL",
        "DefaultContact": false,
        "Value": "sample@xyz.com"
    }
],
"PersonData": {
    "BirthDate": "1968-08-03T00:00:00",
    "CitizenshipCode": "US",
    "DeathDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "FirstName": "John",
    "Gender": "M",
    "LastName": "Jones"
}
```

}

I would like to get a value of CountryCode from the Addresses node where TypeCode is "CORRESPONDENCE". I tried to achieve that with combinations of JSON_VALUE and JSON_QUERY functions but I failed. Below are some examples of my trials:

query:

```
SELECT JSON_QUERY(t.Data, '$.Addresses') AS Address FROM [Table1] t
```

result:

```
[
{
    "ApartmentNumber": "1",
    "City": "Rome",
    "CountryCode": "IT",
    "HouseNumber": "2",
    "Post": "Rome",
    "PostalCode": "11-111",
    "Region": "Rome",
    "Street": "Italian",
    "StreetPrefix": "St.",
    "TypeCode": "PERMANENT"
},
{
    "ApartmentNumber": "11",
    "City": "Madrid",
    "CountryCode": "ES",
    "HouseNumber": "22",
    "Post": "Madrid",
    "PostalCode": "11-111",
    "Region": "Madrid",
    "Street": "Spanish",
    "StreetPrefix": "St.",
    "TypeCode": "CORRESPONDENCE"
}
```

]

or this:

query:

```
 select top 1 JSON_VALUE(t.Data, '$.PersonData.LastName') FROM [Table1] t where ISJSON(t.Data) > 0 and JSON_VALUE(pd.BusinessPartner, '$.PersonData.Gender') = 'F'
```

result:
"Jones"

but when i to write similar query with Addresses as condition:

query:

```
  select top 1 JSON_VALUE(t.Data, '$.Addresses.CountryCode') FROM [Table1] t where ISJSON(t.Data) > 0 and JSON_VALUE(t.Data,'$.Addresses.TypeCode') = 'CORRESPONDENCE'
```

I get empty string as the result.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show what you tried and what the result was, then we can understand exactly what your issue is. Also see the docs at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15 in case that helps you

Comment: P.S. If you have more info and code, please add it to your question, not comments. Use the "edit" button under your question to provide updates, thanks. Code in comments is hard to read and also is not obvious to other readers, it should be displayed in the question. Comments are just for brief discussion and clarification.

Comment: Sure thanks. I have updated the question with some samples of my code

Comment: what's the SQL Server version?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU22-GDR) (KB4583457) - 14.0.3370.1 (X64) 
 Nov  6 2020 18:19:52 
 Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
 Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter 10.0 <X64> (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: The reason why `JSON_VALUE` didn't work at all is because you didn't specify the array index. But with `JSON_VALUE` you cannot get multiple results to check with your filter, so you need `OPENJSON` to crack open the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From SQL Server 2016, you can query on JSON column. See the documentation : [Work with JSON data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server)

The interesting part for you it's [Analyze JSON data with SQL queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server#analyze-json-data-with-sql-queries).

This done :

```sql
select Id, PostalCode
from Address
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (Address.Data, N'$.Addresses')
WITH (
    TypeCode varchar(50) '$.TypeCode',
    PostalCode varchar(50) '$.PostalCode'
) AS AddressesJsonData
WHERE TypeCode  = N'PERMANENT'
```

Comment: It worked however I had to upgrade my database COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL from 120 to 130 for openjson function to work. Thank you very much!