# How to extract specific data from metadata?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need some help on extracting some very specific data from metadata that I have from a database. Here's how part of the code and my metadata looks below. What I only need is "DESC":"Ref 188888", how may I edit the code to get what I need?

Thank you

```
SELECT data.metadata -> 'details' as metadata_info
FROM db_information
```

Results from above query:

{"DATE":null,"CD":"25","TAMT":80.00,"CHENBR":null,"DESC":"Ref 188888","DESS":" APS",........ many other unnecessary stuff}

Comment: Check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67984191/how-to-get-data-from-json-column-in-mssql

Comment: You should really provide create scripts of the two tables to help people help you

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the below script.

```sql
DECLARE @json NVarChar(2048) = N'{
    "DATE": null,
    "CD": "25",
    "TAMT": 80.00,
    "CHENBR": null,
    "DESC": "Ref 188888",
    "DESS": " APS"
}';
 
SELECT *
FROM OpenJson(@json);

SELECT JSON_VALUE(@json, '$.DESC') AS [DESC];
```

Comment: Sorry I don't really know how this works.. So when I put it into SQL, it says syntax error at or near "@".. What should I do here? Thank you :)

Comment: The OPENJSON function is available only under compatibility level 130 or higher. If your database compatibility level is lower than 130, SQL Server can't find and run the OPENJSON function. Other JSON functions are available at all compatibility levels.

You can check compatibility level in the sys.databases view or in database properties. You can change the compatibility level of a database with the following command:

ALTER DATABASE DatabaseName SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 130

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: @bishibashi Can you tell me the version of SQL Server?  “select @@version;”

Comment: I have no clue about the version because I am not an administrator, more like a user only.. And we have a web interface where we key in our commands and the results are displayed in a table

Comment: Refer to this link http://mtkcode.blogspot.com/2014/08/parse-json-string-by-sql-script.html