# How do I query a table in SQL Server that has a JSON column, where that JSON column can result in 0 or Many rows?

Tags: sql, json, t-sql

I have a table `my_table`. Here is a simplified view:

```
id, the_json
1, {json json json}
2, {json}
3, {json json}
```

Here is a sample of what the JSON can look like:

```
{
    "valid":false,
    "messages": {
        {
            "message": "blah",
            "error": true,
            "detail": "something1"
        }
        {
            "message": "blah blah",
            "error": true,
            "detail": "something2"
        }
        {
            "message": "blah blah blah",
            "error": false,
            "detail": "something3"
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to write a query to get the following result (row gaps for visibility):

```
id, message, error, detail

1, blah, true, something1
1, blah blah, true, something2
1, blah blah blah, false, something3

2, blah, true, something1

3, blah, true, something1
3, blah blah, true, something2
```

Aka, each message node in the json should result in a row, and should join back to the parent table to show the id.

Comment: Have you had a look at `OPENJSON`? If not, why not? What *did* you look at when you were researching? What about the articles/answers/documents you read didn't you understand?

Comment: I've seen examples of using openjson, but it always seems to take a @variable and break it out individually, for use in functions or stored procedures, instead of for use in a query's from/join area... I am having trouble trying to adapt it to a regular query.

Comment: Have you had a look at the [documentation's 3rd example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#example-3---join-rows-with-json-data-stored-in-table-cells-using-cross-apply)? Alternatively there's plenty of questions such as [How to get data from json column in mssql](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67984191/2029983). What about those are unclear and we can try to elaborate.

Comment: Ahhh, I think that did the trick! I did see that page, but wasn't really able to tell if Example 3 even applied to the query I was trying to write.

Here is the working query now. Hopefully it's not too hackey:

    select
        mt.id,
        json_value(value, '$.message') as [message],
        json_value(value, '$.error') as [error],
        json_value(value, '$.detail') as [detail],
    from
        my_table as mt
        cross apply openjson(JSON_QUERY(mt.the_json, '$.messages'))

You can post this query as the answer, if you'd like to take credit for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `OPENJSON` function to get separate rows, and you need to do it with a schema to get these columns. To get it per row of your table, you need to `APPLY` it.

Note the use of a second parameter to jumpt straight to `$.messages`

```sql
SELECT
  t.id,
  j.*
FROM YourTable t
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(t.the_json, '$.messages')
  WITH (
    message nvarchar(100),
    error bit,
    detail nvarchar(100)
  ) j;
```

Comment: This is a much more elegant solution than what I was doing yesterday. Thanks!